# Big dataset for hadoop join?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I did some joining operation, both mapside and reduce side, with small dataset. I am looking for a gigabyte scale publicly available dataset for measuring performance on cluster. Do you guys any possible many-to-many join dataset?

Comment: Here is similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10843892/download-large-data-for-hadoop. 
I guess that you find something appropriate. GL

Comment: Thanks @WawrzyniecSz.! I am currently looking into those, yet to find any dataset with multiple files which I can use for joining use hadoop.

Comment: You could add some dummy field like rand(1,row_number/1M) to any of those data sets in map only job. Copy result. Two data sets with many to many relation is ready!