# Sample data for Hadoop

Tags: hadoop

For education purpose I am looking for a large set of data. Data from social networks could be interesting but difficult to obtain. Data from scientific experiments could lead to write very difficult algorithm to have interesting results. Does any one have an idea how / where can I generate / find a large interesting data set ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here are some public data sets I have gathered over time

http://wiki.gephi.org/index.php/Datasets
[Download large data for Hadoop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10843892/download-large-data-for-hadoop)
http://datamob.org/datasets
http://konect.uni-koblenz.de/
http://snap.stanford.edu/data/
http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/
https://bitly.com/bundles/hmason/1
http://www.inside-r.org/howto/finding-data-internet
http://goo.gl/Jecp6
http://ftp3.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/noaa/1990/
http://data.cityofsantacruz.com/
http://bitly.com/bundles/hmason/1

Answer (score 3):

Here Amazon has a list of some huge public datasets you may try out :
http://aws.amazon.com/publicdatasets/

Comment: This answer here would help you more: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10843892/download-large-data-for-hadoop

Comment: yeah i didn't see it where i wrote the question, i set my question to close as duplicate.