# Where to get example data and queries for Big Data Pipeline?

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-pig, bigdata, hue

I am looking for some real world data and queries to be able to use to test hue. The data would need to use different technologies (pig, hive, etc) specifically to create a pipeline. I can find individual pig or hive scripts but not a real world pipeline example involving different frameworks.

I am not fully up to speed on the data side of big data, so it is hard for me to create any real world use cases. Furthermore the examples eg like Spark are trivial like word counts etc.

Where can I dig up some data for a pipeline, with the related steps of the pipeline? That way I can focus on the the Hue UI as required.

Comment: For data sets, you may want to have a look at this reply, http://stackoverflow.com/a/10870801

Answer (score 1):

You could look at the Hue blog, there are some realistic examples with processing [Bike Data with Spark, SQL](http://gethue.com/bay-area-bike-share-data-analysis-with-spark-notebook-part-2/) or [Streaming](http://gethue.com/build-a-real-time-analytic-dashboard-with-solr-search-and-spark-streaming/).